# Combinations: dividing students into 3 groups

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How would you solve a problem: we have $30$ students in a classroom. How could we divide them into three groups, if there needs to be $5$ students in the first group, $10$ students in the second group and 15 students in the third group. The result is: $\frac{30!}{5!×10!×15!}$ . Why isnt it $\frac{30!}{3!×5!×10!×15!}$ since we have three groups with $3!$ permutations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\binom{30}{5}\binom{25}{10}\binom{15}{15}$ is the correct answer

Comment: But that result is written in the book and our teacher solved it on the board, but I still dont get it... how to come to that result

Comment: The groups are distinguished by their sizes.  Choosing who is in each group completely determines the groups.  If you had groups with the same size, then you would have to divide by the number of ways you could choose the same groups.

Comment: I have addressed your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380974/how-many-ways-can-you-divide-9-students-into-three-unlabeled-teams-of-4-3/3382695#3382695).

Comment: But how would you solve: how many ways are there to equally divide 30 students to groups of 10?

Comment: I also addressed that question in the linked question.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: N. F. Taussig I still do not understand how you do not divide with x! when groups differ from each other. I understand why we divide when groups are the same, but do not understand why we divide when they aren't.

Comment: the groups are not distinguished by their size here; they are distinguished by being group 1, group 2, or group 3. group 1 can have size 5, 10 or 15. group 2 can have size 5, 10, or 15. group 3 can have size 5, 10, or 15